# ELK with Filebeat without Log File

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

I have setup my ELK stack with Filebeat to ship my logs, all works fine if I have a log file and add that path to my filebeat.yml

But what if my application has no log files generated and only using console printing logs. How can   I redirect these logs to filebeat?

Tried using the Log file with Filebeat.yml, works fine

Need help with how can we implement the same without log files(Console logs) to Filebeat with ELK Stack

Answer (score 0):

We can enable the console output by adding `output.console` in `filebeat.yml`.

```
output.console:
  pretty: true
```

Please see this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/console-output.html).

Comment: Thanks Swathi, I saw this documentation as well, but how will my SpringBoot application will be linked with Filebeat now? Previously its the Log File of my application which is connects my application and filebeat. But in this case, how will it be?

Comment: Where is your Spring Boot app deployed? If it is running in docker or Kubernetes, we can point the path to *.log on the container.

Comment: Yes, its on Docker. Trying this as a POC now on local tho.